# Classification theorem for separable algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, extension-field, semi-simple-rings

**1. Context**
My lecture notes propose the following structure theorem for separable algebras (which is reminiscent of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem):

> Let $k$ be a field. A $k$-algebra is separable if and only if $A\cong \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^r A_i$ is a direct sum of finite-dimensional, simple $k$-algebras where all $Z(A_i)/k$ are separable extensions of fields.

**2.Question**

- Where can I find a proof of this structure theorem? Alternatively, an outline of a proof would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give a proof in [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/separable-algebras/) although it could probably be simplified and apparently there's a small gap I never got around to plugging. Whoops.